# How to forward declare a typedef structure in C which has no tag

Tags: c, structure, typedef

**file1.h**: Library code. CANT change it

```
#ifndef FILE1_H_
#define FILE1_H_

typedef struct
{
    int x;
} MY_STRUCT;

#endif /* FILE1_H_ */
```

**file2.h**: user defined. can be changed. How to forward declare above typedef struct which has no tag ?

```
#ifndef FILE2_H_
#define FILE2_H_

struct MY_STRUCT;

void print(struct MY_STRUCT * obj);

#endif /* FILE2_H_ *
```

**file2.c: user defined. can be changed**

```
#include "file2.h"
#include "file1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print(struct MY_STRUCT * obj)
{
    printf("x: %d", obj->x);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "file2.h"
#include "file1.h"

int main(void){
    MY_STRUCT obj1;
    obj1.x = 100;
    print(&obj1);
}
```

The code can be seen here. https://paiza.io/projects/wa2PCvUswWyyAzdxxjggxQ?language=c

Comment: Normally `file2.h` should just `#include "file1.h"`.  There isn't really any good way around it.

Comment: Nate is right, a header file should include any other header files that it depends on. But you could have solved the problem simply by including `file1.h` before including `file2.h` in `file2.c` and `main.c`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to "forward-declare" a typedef .  You will have to give the struct a tag, e.g.:

```
typedef struct my_struct MY_STRUCT;

// ... later

struct my_struct
{
    int x;
};
```

Comment: cant change the structure as its part of a library. I know I can always include the library header if forward declaration doesn't work. just wondering any other way possible